# r { : argument is of length zero (already tried !is.null()

Tags: r

If i contains substring 'log' then errors should be 'log' else should be 'not log'.

```
i <- "master_sink"
islog <- grep("log", i)

if( islog==1 ) {
  errors <- 'log'
} else {
  errors <- 'not log'
}
Error in if (islog == 1) { : argument is of length zero
```

So tried:

```
if( !is.null(islog) && islog==1 ) {
  errors <- 'log'
} else {
  errors <- 'not log'
}
Error in if (!is.null(islog) && islog == 1) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I have tried many variations after reading several SO posts but I keep getting errors.

Comment: Try `if(length(islog) > 0)`, or `grepl("log", i)`, which returns TRUE/FALSE.

Comment: That did it, thank you

Comment: You could just do `if(length(islog))` because `if()` will coerce `length` to logical.  `grepl()` should only be used when you are certain the output will always be length 1.

Comment: @RichScriven "grepl() should only be used when you are certain the output will always be length 1". Is there a more appropriate "r esque" way to check if a string contains a substring?

Comment: `grepl()` *is* the appropriate way.  However, inside an `if()` statement you need to be careful, because the `if()` statement only accepts a statement that evaluates to length 1.  Otherwise you'll get a *the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used* warning and your results may not be correct.  That's all I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `if(length(islog) > 0)`, or `grepl("log", i)`, which returns TRUE/FALSE.